# JMeter: While condition with property value

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I currently have a problem with While Controller in JMeter
I have a While Controller with many steps inside it, the final step has a BeanShell Assertion with something like this

```
${__setProperty(sessionUID_global,${sessionUID})};
```

I'm trying to put a condition for While Controller like this:

```
${__javaScript(vars.get("sessionUID_global") == null)}
```

But, It's not working
Could anyone help me to stop the while controller with a condition when sessionUID_global has a value?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
${__javaScript(vars.get("sessionUID_global") == null)}
```

to this:

```
${__javaScript(props.get("sessionUID_global") == null)}
```

Going forward:

1. Consider switching from the Beanshell Assertion to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/) with the following code:

   ```
   props.put('sessionUID_global', vars.get('sessionUID'))
   ```
2. Consider migrating While Controller's condition to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(props.get("sessionUID_global") == null)}
   ```

As [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting

Comment: ${__javaScript(props.get("sessionUID_global") == null)} is giving me false. I'll try restarting to check what is happening.

Comment: It works, It looks like the property was still in JMeter's memory. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

JMeter variables are never null.
To check the condition, you can use for example:

```
${__javaScript(vars.get("sessionUID_global")>0)}
```

Comment: Does it read properties setted with "setProperty"? That condition looks like not working for me :(

Comment: Try this if not please share the log... 

`props.put("sessionUID_global", vars.get("sessionUID"));`

`props.get("sessionUID_global")`